# What does 东突之敌 mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am reading the article  titled 沙场骁将浩气长存——沉痛悼念杨勇同志  in 人民日報, published on 1983/01/22. It describes the combat tactics of PRC general [楊勇](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yang_Yong_(general)), who had just passed away. A passage reads:

> 第一旅在西关向城内进行主要攻击；第二旅在北关向城内实施助攻；第十九旅主力调郓城东关，随时准备歼灭**东突**之敌；各旅突破后，迅速向纵深穿插、割裂敌人而歼灭之。

The question is, what 东突之敌 means here. Today we see the character combination in connection to those who wish to establish an „East Turkestan“. I don’t think that is the meaning here. Here we are talking about a battle between GMD and KPC.

I would roughly translate:

> The first Brigade at Xiguang carried out the primary strike at the city centre. 
>   The second brigade at Beiguan executed the auxiliary strike at the city centre. The nineteenth brigade’s Main force tranfered to Dongguan at Yuncheng and prepared to annihilate the Dongtu enemy??? in due time...

In 突破 the 突 appears with the meaning of „dash forward, “break through”. Is 东突之敌 the enemy who had broken through in the east?

---

Even larger part of the text:

> 我感到，杨勇同志之所以军政全优，指挥有方，能驾驭战场的千变万化，掌握战争的主动权，一个成功的经验，是他有刻苦顽强的钻研精神。在戎马倥偬的岁月里，他努力学习毛主席的军事思想，认真领会上级的意图。由于他较多地接触刘、邓首长，尤其善于把刘、邓首长的作战指挥思想，运用于自己指挥的战役战斗，所以在作战指挥中，形成了一种决心果断、指挥灵活、能攻善守、英勇顽强的战斗风格。在1947年7月的鲁西南战场上，我们将郓城之敌包围。敌人是国民党五十五师师部和两个旅。该敌善于阵地防守，在郓城四周布满了地堡群及暗堡射击孔。面对这样一个强劲敌人，杨勇同志根据刘、邓首长关于“攻城部队一定要选择敌防御薄弱、对我有利地段为主攻方向，集中兵力火力突破”的经验，当即命令第二十旅在南关向城内实施主要攻击；第一旅在西关向城内进行主要攻击；第二旅在北关向城内实施助攻；第十九旅主力调郓城东关，随时准备歼灭东突之敌；各旅突破后，迅速向纵深穿插、割裂敌人而歼灭之。一夜激战，全歼守敌五十五师师部及二十九、七十四两个整旅，共达15，000余人，受到了刘、邓首长的通令嘉奖。郓城战斗结束后，我第一纵队在杨勇同志指挥下，迅速组织了六营集战斗。六营集是个不大的村庄，挤满了1万多敌人。原计划以我纵队及第6纵队主力，从六营集南、北、西三路包围实施总攻击，一举全歼敌人。后来杨勇同志考虑到：若迫敌为困兽之计，其兵力火力集中，我付代价必大，莫如趁敌兵力拥挤混乱、企图突围之际，诱敌于野外歼灭之。这一打算，得到邓小平政委批准。六营集东南方有一块几平方公里的大洼地，杨勇同志决心用“围三阙一”的方法，网开一面，虚留生路，作为敌人的“逃路”。夜晚，为了给敌人以“安全”感，杨勇同志让驻守在这里的文工团、通信营、卫生所等纵队直属单位加强灯火管制。走投无路的敌人，发现这里尚存一线生机，就在深夜全部钻进了我们准备好了的“口袋阵”。战斗历时3日，歼敌两个相当军的整编师，创造了运动战的范例。

Comment: Yes, your interpretation is correct.

Comment: Yes , 东突之敌 means 'enemy who had broken through in the east' or ' enemy who attempts to break  through from the East'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you interpretation is correct. 东 here means 从东方，突 means 突破，therefore 东突之敌 means（尝试）从东边突破（包围圈）的敌人。

Comment: IMHO, 向东突进 may be better because it shows that the enemy did not succeed to breakthrough. "从东边突破" seems to show that the enemy had already breakthrough.

Comment: @T-Pioneer You are right, maybe 尝试从东边突破的敌人 is better.